# button does not top-align - solution without pos: absolute

Tags: html, css

Im trying to figure out why the blue bordered buttons "points forts" and "caracteristiques" dont top-align on this [site](http://enairbec.effetweb.ca/produits/) I'm building.

I know how to use the inspection and css to align that stuff usually, but this one I can't seem to figure out.

I would love to avoid using absolute positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a top margin on `class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element produits_innertabs_btn"` somewhere that is at 80px that is preventing the buttons from top-aligning and also get rid of the `<br>` between the buttons

Found the margin on `line 1426` of custom.css

Comment: @ulumi if it was correct please mark the answer as the solution thank you